# Cannot find 'SessionManager' in scope?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift5, rxalamofire

I'm updating my code with RxAlamofire. I updated RxAlmofire with lastest version. How can i update this code `config.httpAdditionalHeaders = SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders` in

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    config.httpAdditionalHeaders = SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
```

I tried with `config.httpAdditionalHeaders = HTTPHeader.defaultUserAgent` but not success

Comment: Did you import `RxAlamofire`?

Comment: Yes, i did. But Alamofire5 has renamed ```SessionManager``` to ```Session```. And session has no member is ```defaultHTTPHeaders```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alamofire5 has renamed `SessionManager` to `Session`

Follow the migration guide [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%205.0%20Migration%20Guide.md)

, and so as to RxAlamofire

Comment: ```Session``` has no member ```defaultHTTPHeaders```

Comment: `config.headers = .default`